# How to hide "jQuery (jQ)" Tooltip in "Firefox (FF)" after click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

**PROBLEM**

I use ajax in asp.net with "ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager". After click on button and changing ajax content "jQ Tooltip" doesn't disappears. This happens only in FF.

How solve hiding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After each asynchronous request run the code that removes all forgotten "JQ Tooltip" elements

```
$("[id*='ui-tooltip-']").remove();
```

Here is whole example that may help

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    pageRequestManager.add_pageLoaded(tooltop_onEndAsyncRequest);

});

function tooltop_onEndAsyncRequest(sender, args) {

    // fix ff
    $("[id*='ui-tooltip-']").remove();

    $(".Tooltip").live("mouseover", function () {

        $(this).tooltip({
            // ...
        });

    });

}
```